# How to get tap of two buttons in View for annotation in ios?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have made a view in `didSelectAnnotationView` and have added two buttons on it with different tags, when `didDeselectAnnotationView` is called I get subviews of the annotation view and want to perform two different actions on both of those buttons. But I don't get to know which button is being tapped on `Annotation` view.

Answer (score 0):

You should define this line of code to both of you buttons

```
[yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And define `- (IBAction)yourFunction:(id)sender`

So whenever you click it will take you to function `yourFunction`

It will help.thanks

Comment: then u didn't write this pice of code in a right place.

Comment: please help! i have tried all such possibilities... if you have somthing else in mind...

Comment: can you share the code with us. .it will help us to find the problem